# User Specific Reporting with SQL Azure Reporting Services

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, azure, azure-sql-database

Is there any solution to user-specific reporting with Azure SSRS? I have an Azure database with a user table and only want my reports to query data pertaining to the user.

Any tips/alternatives would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Azure SSRS supports the User!UserID property so you can use it for user-specific reporting and that would be the easiest way to get it done.

Also about filtering SQL query using the user_name() may work or not. If you use ‘Stored Credential’ option for the RS data source, the same credential will be shared by multiple users. In that case, you can’t rely on user_name(). If you use ‘Prompt’, and if each user needs to supply a unique credential for himself or herself, then you can use user_name().

Answer (score 1):

Does Azure SSRS support the User!UserID property? If not, you should be able to filter in the SQL query using the user_name() function.

Answer (score 0):

these guys actually implemented user specific SQL queries in their report. check it out:
http://www.upsizing.co.uk/Art68_ReportViewerControlAndSQLAzure.aspx